# Sort null values in last

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort `null` values on last.

First error occurred when `S1 = ""` or `S2 = ""` in `SortInteger` function.
    Second I want to sort `null` values to *end*.

```
 result.Sort((x, y) => SortInteger(x.ID.ToString(), y.ID.ToString(), sortDirection));
```

ID can contain `null` value.

```
private int SortInteger(string s1, string s2, string sortDirection)
{
    int i1 = int.Parse(s1);
    int i2 = int.Parse(s2);
    return sortDirection == "asc" ? i1.CompareTo(i2) : i2.CompareTo(i1);
}
```

First error occurred when `S1 = ""` or `S2 = ""` in `SortInteger` function.
Second I want to sort `null` values to *end*.

Answer (score 7):

You have to consider **4** cases:

1. Both `s1` and `s2` are valid integers
2. Only `s1` is valid integer
3. Only `s2` is valid integer
4. Neither `s1` nor `s2` are valid integers

Since `string` is not necessary a *valid* `int`, try `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`.

**Code:**

```
private static int SortInteger(string s1, string s2, string sortDirection)
{
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;

    bool isInt1 = int.TryParse(s1, out i1);
    bool isInt2 = int.TryParse(s2, out i2);

    if (isInt1 && isInt2)
      return sortDirection == "asc" ? i1.CompareTo(i2) : i2.CompareTo(i1);
    else if (isInt1)
      return sortDirection == "asc" ? -1 : 1;
    else if (isInt2)
      return sortDirection == "asc" ? 1 : -1;
    else
      return sortDirection == "asc" ? string.Compare(s1, s2) : string.Compare(s2, s1);
}
```